# Laravel - insert DB::rollback Unique key prevention

Tags: php, database, laravel

my table column **entry_id** column is set to unique...

Is there any best way to use try & catch and DB::rollback to modify my variable? eg:

```
$_id     = 1
$entryId = 'test0000'+$_id;
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $sub = Submission::create([
        'entry_id' => $entryId,
    ]);
    DB::commit();
    // success insert..

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    //detected unique... just ++ _id to ensure not unique
    $_id++;
    // throw $e;
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    //detected unique... just ++ _id to ensure not unique
    $_id++;
    // throw $e;
}
```

First time wouldn't have error, may I know the 2nd time, to ensure **entry_id** is not unique, could I entry++ using rollback method? is this the correct way?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case is better to use a closure.

```
DB::transaction(function() use ($entryId)
{
    $sub = Submission::create([
        'entry_id' => $entryId,
    ]);
});
```

You can chain your queries inside the closure and it will run a rollback automatically if it fails at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Check If your Tables Engine =MyISAM

and change it to InnoDB

In Laravel open config/database.php
in mysql set engine => 'InnoDB'

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => "InnoDB",
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
],
```

after that fresh the migration
to change the engine in the database